# Beginner Java Code not working - While loop error

Tags: java

I have an error in the while loop. The While Statement is showing as an error in Eclipse? What am I missing... (Yes I know it is simple code... I am going to start with beginner code first.

```
/**
* @author Nathan
*
*/
public class DietCokeSong { 
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int dietCokeNum = 99;
    String word = "Cans of Diet Coke";
    While(dietCokeNum > 0) {

        System.out.println(dietCokeNum + " " + word + " on the wall");
        System.out.println(dietCokeNum + " " + word + ".");
        System.out.println("Take one down.");
        System.out.println("Pass it around.");

        dietCokeNum = dietCokeNum - 1;

        if(dietCokeNum > 0) {
            System.out.println(dietCokeNum + " " + word + " on the wall");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No more Cans of Diet Coke on the wall.");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Whilst this one is pretty trivial, in your future questions you should always copypaste the **exact** error/exception message and stacktrace instead of generalizing it with "an error". It namely contains the answer to your problem. You just have to find someone who can translate it in layman's terms for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The W in "while" should not be capitalized.  I think that is all.

Comment: Thanks I knew it was simple the error thought it was a missing ";"

Comment: @NathanStanford: When your compiler says dumb things like "missing semicolon", don't believe what it says -- look for the real problem. It may in fact be a missing semicolon, but it's more likely something else.

Comment: In your case, the compiler thought that `While(dietCokeNum > 0)` was a *function call*, and was probably expecting a semicolon instead of the following `{`.

Answer (score 3):

`while` should be in lower case.... and "diet coke" should be "beer"...

Comment: Yeah... I hear ya but I am the one writing this. LOL  Plus I hope to teach some little kids this.